# Mvel expression not working in Drools

Tags: drools, mvel

I have the following Java rule in a Drools LHS:

```
Policy(((Person)contacts.get(0)).getHouseHold() == null)
```

This works. I was expecting that I could change that to an mvel expression like this:

```
Policy(contacts[0]#Person.houseHold == null)
```

or this:

```
Policy((contacts[0])#Person.houseHold == null)
```

or even this:

```
Policy(((contacts[0])#Person).houseHold == null)
```

This however gives the following error when I compile the drools rules:

> mismatched input '#' in rule "Rule1"

What's wrong with my mvel expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
$contact: contacts[0], $contact#Person.houseHold == null
```

I guess mvel or drools cannot handle a typecast of an element of a list directly.